# Can I add standard ivars and properties to an NSManagedObject?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, nsmanagedobject

Can I add standard properties to an NSManagedObject. I don't expect these objects to be saved, but I would like them to persist for the lifetime that the application is running.

Can I add a getter and setter backed with an ivar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case "transient properties" are commonly used. You declare them in your Core Data Model like your other Entity properties but flag them as "transient" in the data model inspector. They are part of your Core Data model, but not persisted!
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would I be correct in thinking that standard properties will not be persisted as the object itself might be different each time a ManagedObject is accessed? What I'm noticing is that if I have a ManagedObject - SomeObject - each time I fetch it I am actually getting back a different object/instance.

Comment: 1. The standard (non CD) properties won't be persisted, since the ´@synthesize´ keyword, that sets up a property along with its accessors and filling them with data is up to the user. CD properties have the keyword ´@dynamic´ in front, which means, that CD handles the creation and **initial** data supply of the properties for the user. 2. Yes, i've observed that, too, but i don't know if it is the reason for the above behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps that is another question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938229/core-data-returns-a-different-object-instance-for-the-same-nsmanagedobject-each/10938271#comment14272310_10938271

Comment: I'm not really sure this is the correct answer; it's a little misleading as you don't need to create transient properties unless you'll be using them in your Core Data fetches, etc.  For normally properties and ivars, the correct answer is 'Yes', you can create them as you would with any other object, as answered by @melsam below.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: You cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties (although you can use transient properties to filter in memory yourself).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can add your own properties and methods to a class derived from NSManagedObject. I do this all the time. You can declare the properties @dynamic (if using Core Data), or simply @synthesize them.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm noticing is that if I set a value on a standard property, that value is not persisted the next time I access that object. I think this is because each time you access a ManagedObject you are actually getting back a different object which populates its properties from Core Data.

Comment: Persisted where? in memory or in the database? If memory, are you declaring and instantiating the object correctly?

Comment: Persisted during the application lifecycle. If there is a single ManagedObject of type SomeManagedObject, each time I fetch that object, I get a different instance back. I'm assuming its just the way COre Data works. So if I use standard properties, I can fetch the object, set a value, then if I fetch it again the value will be unset, while dynamic properties defined in my CoreData model are correctly set.

Comment: It depends on how and where the ManagedObject itself is created and its own lifetime. As far as I know, standard properties for managed objects behave just like standard properties on any other class.