# Core Data returns a different object instance for the same NSManagedObject each time I fetch it. Why is this?

Tags: ios, core-data, fetch, nsmanagedobject

I have recently noticed that if I fetch a ManagedObject of which I can verify that there is only one in the model and which is not retained anywhere in my application, every time the fetch returns the object it is a different instance (with a pointer to a different memory adress). Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no one retains it, Core Data is free to release it.  If you ask for it again, it will probably be at a different memory location.   You can't count on it being the same object instance.

Comment: So in effect Core Data is creating the ManagedObjects that represent its data as they are needed. It doesn't persist the objects because it already has the data persisted in a database?

Comment: It can, but it doesn't have to.  You can't count on it.  Also, it can have in-memory versions of the data (so it doesn't need to refetch), but doesn't need to store that in NSManagedObjects.

Answer (score 1):

A given `NSManagedObject` is tied to a specific `NSManagedObjectContext`, so if you change contexts, you will necessarily change objects. If the object faults, you may also receive a new instance if the MOC has released the object. This is part of how Core Data keeps memory usage low.